# Hibernate. ManyToOne generate n+1 select

Tags: hibernate, many-to-one

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Articulo")
public class Articulo implements Serializable { 
        @Id
        @ManyToOne  
        @JoinColumn(name="cod_familia")
        Familia familia;    
        @Id
        String cod_articulo;    
        String lit_articulo;
        char estado;

    @Entity
    @Table(name="familia")
    public class Familia {

        @Id
        String cod_familia;
        String lit_familia;
        char estado;
```

With this 2 class when i list all "articulo":

```
public List<Articulo> list() {
    return session().createCriteria(Articulo.class).list();
}
```

hibernate generate 1 select joining both tables and then 1 for each family...

how can i solve this problem???

Answer (score 0):

The reason is an additional `@Id` annotation here

```
@Id
@ManyToOne  
@JoinColumn(name="cod_familia")
Familia familia;
```

Without this annotation Hibernate doesn't use additional selects

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Articulo")
public class Articulo {

    @Id
    private String codArticulo;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "cod_familia")
    private Familia familia;

}

    select
        this_.f_cod_articulo as f_cod_ar1_0_1_,
        this_.cod_familia as cod_fami2_0_1_,
        familia2_.f_cod_familia as f_cod_fa1_1_0_ 
    from
        Articulo this_ 
    left outer join
        familia familia2_ 
            on this_.cod_familia=familia2_.f_cod_familia
```

**Update**

You can add an additional surrogate primary key and a unique constraint.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Articulo",
        uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(
        columnNames = { "cod_articulo", "cod_familia" }))
public class Articulo implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "cod_articulo")
    private String codArticulo;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "cod_familia")
    private Familia familia;

}
```

Comment: @Gwaihir Please, add how you load `Articulo` to your question.

Comment: @Gwaihir Which  Hibernate version you use? Do you really have an `@Id` annotation here `@Id
        @ManyToOne  
        @JoinColumn(name="cod_familia")`?

Comment: yes, articulo have an composite id (cod_familia, cod_articulo). And cod_familia is fk from familia

Comment: Without @id hibernate cross data because codarticulo could be repeat and take the same familia for all.